# How do I fix this SQL SELECT statement for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL `SELECT` statement for MS Access that does exactly what I want when the `PlayerNo` field in both tables - `HPFoulsPoints` and `VPFoulsPoints` is a number type:

```
Select  HPFoulsPoints.*
      , 1 As OrderTbl
From    HPFoulsPoints
Union All
Select  VPFoulsPoints.*
      , 2 As OrderTbl
From    VPFoulsPoints
Order By OrderTbl
      , PlayerNo
```

I need to change `PlayerNo` field to text type, but still have the `PlayerNo` fields sorted by numeric value order just as above `SELECT` does so I thought it would be easy to just do the following:

```
Select  HPFoulsPoints.*
      , 1 As OrderTbl
From    HPFoulsPoints
Union All
Select  VPFoulsPoints.*
      , 2 As OrderTbl
From    VPFoulsPoints
Order By OrderTbl
      , Val(PlayerNo)
```

That `SELECT` does not work; I get the following error:

> Error: -2147217913
>   Description: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The ORDER BY expression (Val(PlayerNo)) includes fields that are not selected by the query. Only those fields requested in the first query can be included in an ORDER BY expression.

How can I fix the `SELECT` above to use `ORDER BY OrderTbl, Val(PlayerNo)` to work exactly like the first `SELECT` at the top that works with just `ORDER BY OrderTbl, PlayerNo`?

Remember I need the new `SELECT` where `PlayerNo` is a text type field to work just like the top `SELECT` where `PlayerNo` is a number type field!

Comment: perhaps just cast it back to a numeric after the val so it sorts as numeric.  `order by cint(val(playerNo))`?  is `PlayerNo` still the valid field name in `HPFoulsPoints & VPFoulsPoints` after you changed the data type?

Comment: Yes - PlayerNo is still the valid field name in HPFoulsPoints and VPFoulsPoints just the type was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to encapsulate everything you have (except the order by clause) in a sub query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT HPFoulsPoints.*, 1 AS OrderTbl
    FROM HPFoulsPoints
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VPFoulsPoints.*, 2 AS OrderTbl
    FROM VPFoulsPoints
    ) AS a
ORDER BY a.OrderTbl, Val(a.PlayerNo)
```

Edited the SQL to reflect the suggestions/corrections in comments, in case someone else stumbles across this.

Comment: Did you mean  - ORDER BY a.OrderTbl, a.Val(PlayerNo) ?

Comment: I tried the SQL above used ORDER BY a.OrderTbl, a.Val(PlayerNo) and of  course it does not like a.Val(PlayerNo) so how do you do that? Maybe Val(a.PlayerNo)??

Comment: I got it your encapsulate guided me to an answer: I just needed it to be SELECT * FROM ( ... ) AS a ORDER BY a.OrderTbl, Val(a.PlayerNo)  -- that works - thanks!

Comment: @NealDavis  I must admit i'm baffled how this solves sorting text as number.  have you checked if you have player 1 and 10 that they are sorted in numeric order?  oh I see your comment val(a.playerNo) casts it to numeric so it is sorting numeric.

Comment: @xQbert - see my final answer below; after changing to ORDER BY a.OrderTbl, Val(a.PlayerNo) it does sort the text field PlayerNo correctly: 1,2,3,11,22,33 as I need it to

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final correct SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT HPFoulsPoints.*, 1 AS OrderTbl
    FROM HPFoulsPoints
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VPFoulsPoints.*, 2 AS OrderTbl
    FROM VPFoulsPoints
    ) AS a
ORDER BY a.OrderTbl, Val(a.PlayerNo)
```